# Pixelisation of an image

Tags: c, image

can you say me if this function to pixelise an image is correct ?
Image are in .ppm format.

```
Image* pixelisation_image(Image* I) {
     int i, j, x, y;
     int h = I->h, w = I->w;
     int n;
     int moyenne_r = 0;
     int moyenne_g = 0;
     int moyenne_b = 0;
     int tmpi, tmpj;
     printf("Enter your size of pixel : ");
     scanf("%d", &n);
     for(i = 0; i < (h/n)-1; i++){
         for(j = 0; j < (w/n)-1; j++){
             for(x = 0; x < n; x++){
                 for(y = 0; y < n; y++){
                     tmpi = n*i + x;
                     tmpj = n*j + y;
                     moyenne_r += I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].r;
                     moyenne_v += I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].g;
                     moyenne_b += I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].b;
                 }
             }
             for(x = 0; x < n; x++){
                 for(y = 0; y < n; y++){
                     tmpi = n*i + x;
                     tmpj = n*j + y;
                     I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].r = moyenne_r/9;
                     I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].v = moyenne_g/9;
                     I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].b = moyenne_b/9;
                 }
             }
             moyenne_r = 0;
             moyenne_g = 0;
             moyenne_b = 0;
         }
     }
     return I;
 }
```

With this struct for Image :

```
typedef struct structPixel {
    unsigned char r,g,b;
}Pixel; 

typdef struct structImage {
    int w, h;
    int max;
    int magic_number;
    Pixel** tab;
} Image;
```

Where n is the size of the final "block of pixel".

Then I need to put a low pass and high pass filters. I understand clearly that I need to make a mask of 3x3, resize it to 5x5 and then make the sum 4 times. But I try and try and I can't do it. Can you give me paths for reflection and action please ?

Globaly, i'm not sure that is the best way to treat .ppm image, can you give me some advices ?

Thanks you a lot.

Comment: what is `n`? Also you should use English when coding, it helps people around the world to understand what you are doing. RGB means something for everyone, but RV(ert)B... well you ask for trouble.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pixelate image in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547125/pixelate-image-in-code)

Comment: Okey yes I will check this, and yes I will edit this for explain n ( size of pixel's block and the french words)

Comment: Mm yes I was wondering if a low pass filter is equal to a pixelisation ?

Comment: But how is it actualy with my code ? When I run it, it pixelise the image but is it a good way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an extra loop without any reason, you could rewrite it this way:

```c
Image* pixelisation_image(Image* I) {
     int i, j, x, y;
     int h = I->h, w = I->w;
     int n;
     int tmpi, tmpj;
     printf("Enter your size of pixel : ");
     scanf("%d", &n);
     for(i = 0; i < (h/n)-1; i++){
         for(j = 0; j < (w/n)-1; j++){
             int moyenne_r = 0;
             int moyenne_g = 0;
             int moyenne_b = 0;
             for(x = 0; x < n; x++){
                 for(y = 0; y < n; y++){
                     tmpi = n*i + x;
                     tmpj = n*j + y;
                     moyenne_r += I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].r;
                     moyenne_v += I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].g;
                     moyenne_b += I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].b;
                     I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].r = moyenne_r/9;
                     I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].v = moyenne_g/9;
                     I->tab[tmpi][tmpj].b = moyenne_b/9;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return I;
 }
```