# how to Pixelize a Image with JavaFX?

Tags: java, image, javafx

I want to pixelize a Image with JavaFx.
My problem is that I only have one written pixel in the end, so that it works for just one time.

i tried a

Here is my code:

```
Image img = imgView.getImage();
        PixelReader pixelReader = img.getPixelReader();

        WritableImage wImage = new WritableImage(
                (int) img.getWidth(),
                (int) img.getHeight());

        PixelWriter pixelWriter = wImage.getPixelWriter();


        for (int y = 1; y < img.getHeight(); y += 3) {
            for (int x = 1; x < img.getWidth(); x += 3) {
                Color px = pixelReader.getColor(x, y);


                float red = (float) px.getRed();
                float green = (float) px.getGreen();
                float blue = (float) px.getBlue();

                Color all = new Color(red / 3, green / 3, blue / 3, 1);


                for (int u = 0; u <= 3; u++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                        pixelWriter.setColor(u, i, all);
                    }
                }


            }

        }
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Related: [Help with the theory behind a pixelate algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4047031/6395627)

Answer (score 1):

Just check the part where you set the color:

```
                for (int u = 0; u <= 3; u++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                        pixelWriter.setColor(u, i, all);
                    }
                }
```

As you can see you always set the color of pixel at (0,0) - (3,3). 
You need to use

```
                     pixelWriter.setColor(x + u, y + i, all);
```

However, you need to be sure that you won't try to set color of some pixels outside the image. Check the boundaries of loops by x, y, u and i.